# Alteração de linhas específicas em arquivo .txt

Tags: python, pdf, txt

gostaria de automatizar uma rotina que faço com frequência. Porém ainda não identifiquei a biblioteca que possa suprir minha necessidade.

O problema em questão é o seguinte:
Possuo arquivos TXT que possuem delimitadores "|" para cada coluna e registro.
Exemplo:

linha1: |Armazém|Quadra|Quantidade|Valor|Produto|

linha2: |B|450|652|400|GOIABA|

linha3: |B|470|642|400|GOIABA VERDE|

A solução que pretendo executar é fazer o upload do meu arquivo original e o arquivo com as correções. O arquivo com as correções pode ser .pdf ou txt, porém o novo arquivo gerado tem que ser obrigatoriamente com a estrutura dos "|" e em formato .txt

**Prática:**

Arquivo original:

|B|450|652|400|GOIABA|

|B|470|642|400|GOIABA VERDE|

|B|470|489|400|FEIJAO|

Arquivo com as correções:

|B|450|200|120|GOIABA|

|B|470|789|40|GOIABA VERDE|

**Arquivo final:**

|B|450|200|120|GOIABA|

|B|470|789|40|GOIABA VERDE|

|B|470|489|400|FEIJAO|

Comment: Você pode manipular com fopen() para ler e com fgets() para ler linha por linha e explode('|') para dividir as colunas, e depois salvar em um array e depois reescrever com o arquivo com fopen('arquivo', 'w'). Você também pode usar https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php para ler linha por linha, se precisar de escapes.